# Where do filetype-specific autocommands live?

Tags: autocmd, filetype-tex, filetype

I have a plugin for a specific filetype (`*.tex`), and I'm wondering where I can find all the commands which are executed when I type `:e examplefile.tex`? In general, is there a standardized practice for where to keep filetype-specific autocommands within a plugin?

Comment: Your post has two questions and they're not very related to each other... Would you please post the second part in a new separate question? When you do, please post more details about your macro, how it's defined, where it's defined (in your vimrc?) It's hard to figure out what's wrong without more context... Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden Yup, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Do ask the second question! It's an interesting one... But please do add more context when you do. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim will load filetype-specific commands from an `ftplugin`. See [`:help ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin).

In short, you can create a file under `~/.vim/ftplugin` (or `%HOME%\vimfiles\ftplugin` on Windows), or better `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` (or `%HOME%\vimfiles\after\ftplugin`) named after the filetype for which it should be loaded.

For example, when a file is detected with `filetype=tex`, Vim will load files `ftpugin/tex.vim`, `ftplugin/tex_*.vim` and `ftplugin/tex/*.vim` (from both `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/after`), so you can use a suffix after an `_` or a subdirectory if you want to manage multiple separate files with commands.

Usually, it's better to use the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` directory for your user ftplugins, because this directory is loaded last and the commands in it will run after the filetype-specific scripts from `$VIMRUNTIME` have loaded. Usually, that means you can have the final say on the value of options, if you're loading from `~/.vim/after`.

Note that ftplugins are loaded based on the *filetype* and not the *extension* of the file! There's a process by which Vim autocmds will define what to set the `'filetype'` option to, when opening a file. It usually bases the decision on the file extension (or the whole filename in many cases), but it can often include inspecting the contents of the file itself.

For example, a `*.tex` file can get `'filetype'` set to either `tex` (which actually means it's a LaTeX file), or `plaintex` (pure TeX). If you typically edit LaTeX only, you might want to add `let g:tex_flavor = "latex"` to your vimrc in order to make that the default. See [`:help ft-tex-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ft-tex-plugin) for more details on how the auto-detection works.

If you want to add auto-detection for new filetypes, see [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype). The [`:help plugin-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#plugin-filetype) section also has useful information, you might want to take a peek at that one as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other tips-n-tricks:

- with tpope/scriptease, you can use `:Vedit` (and other variants) to fill the location list with all runtimepath entries matching the provided file (e.g., `:Vedit ftplugin/tex.vim`)
- to actually put an autocommand on a specific filetype, such as "automatically run `:Require` on clojure files when they save," you can use a `<buffer>`-based autocommand in your ftplugin:

```
augroup CljRequire
  " can't use autocmd! here because it would clear the group entirely
  autocmd! * <buffer>
  autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> silent! Require
augroup END
```

and the matching `b:undo_ftplugin` entry is `'autocmd! CljRequire * <buffer>'`.

Comment: Amazing. After some searching I honestly don't think this information on putting an auto-command on a specific filetype is actually specified anywhere else. Not including the `* <buffer>` after the `autocmd!`, as I had been doing up till now, leads to weird results.